# How to display Ȳ (&#562;) properly in Android?

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to display this character Ȳ Ȳ . All other characters display correctly except this(Ȳ). For example, ↑ , displays well but not Ȳ.

[image]

I've tried both Ȳ and the code(Ȳ) like:

```
mEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h5><font color=\"Gray\">&#562;</font></h5>");
mEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h5><font color=\"Gray\">Ȳ</font></h5>");
```

How can I display this character correctly?

[image]

Comment: If you see Y-bar 2 times, i wrote "& # 5 6 2 ;" , the code of this character.thanks.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu yep,i've just tried and again same result..the BAR is right side of Y character!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `\u0232` as a String:

```
mEditText.setText("\u0232");
```

I found out the unicode value using Android Studio’s context menu option “Convert to Basic Latin” which has been helpful quite often recently.

[image: Android Studio right-click menu]

---

> Got same result; the overhead bar is at right of Y

Curious! I just tried what I recommended using an EditText as well as a Toast (as can be seen in my previous screenshot) and both worked just as expected.

[image: Test within EditText]

Comment: Got same result; the overhead bar is at right of Y !

Comment: I'm using BlueStack...maybe it's because of this.Let me check with other tools.TnX.

Comment: Good news :))    I've tried it over my Nexus 5 and the result is good, the bar exactly over the Y.   the problem was BlueStacks..Thanks again.

Comment: Fine it is solved, I thought of "Y&#x0304;" splitting into Y and combining diacritical mark macron, but I guess that is what BlueStack did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is where to run an app...I've run that app in ***BlueStacks*** and result wasn't good but over Nexus 5 the **Ȳ** displayed properly.So if you use ***BlueStacks*** and these kind of character just ignore the shape and check over real Android device.