# Typing Turkish Utf-8 characters in android edittext does not show

Tags: android, utf-8, android-edittext

When I type Turkish language characters (ç,ğ,ş) in `EditText`, It does not admit and does not show any exception, how can I this ? thanks advance.

I am using android studio, genymotion emulator (also I tried on avd and real phone)

my layout descriptions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/et_word"
    android:hint="@string/hint_word"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not admit"?

Comment: I tried to put a random EditText and write your characters, without doing something special it worked well. So can you post your code or can you explain what happen when you press on them?

Comment: I mean it doesn't show these characters

Comment: Check this [other answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27402905/1791820) and try converting to Basic Latin.